# While-loop + fgets error

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
int main ()
{
    char ans[100];
    int count;
    count=0;
    char *arr[100];
    char *srtarr[100];

    while(count<100)
    {
        if(strcmp(ans,"done\n")!=0)  
        {      
            printf("Enter names when done type done:");
            fgets(ans,100,stdin);       
            arr[count]=strdup(ans);
        }
        printf("%s",arr[count]);
        count++;
     }

    system("pause");
    return 0;   
}
```

When I run this code the program stops working. Im very new to c and might have made a few errors. I think the problem is either the while loop or the fgets() function.

EDIT: I corrected the while loop however I'm not understanding how to initialize the array. Doesn't each element within the array get filled as the loop progresses?

Comment: First time: `strcmp(arr[0-1],"done")` and `arr` is not even initialized.

Comment: Exit the loop when `fgets()== NULL) || count >= 100`.

Answer (score 4):

You initialize 'count' to 0, hit the while loop and use 'count - 1' as an array index.  An array index of -1 definitely could crash your program.

Comment: Though that's only one of the many problems with the code. The pointers aren't even initialized at all.

Comment: Indeed; the code should use a `do{}while();` instead.

Comment: Also, what happens when the user doesn't type 'done' and count goes beyond 100?  Down you go.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two cases of [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code:

1. You don't in initialize any of the arrays, meaning the pointers in them are indeterminate.
2. You use a negative index in the first iteration.

Also, you should not forget that [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) leave the newline in the string, so your string comparison will never succeed.

---

My recommended solution: A loop while `count` is less than `100`, then inside the loop check for `"done"` (or rather `"done\n"`) using `ans` (before duplicating it) and break out of the loop then.